# Variable name length in C vs newer languages

Tags: javascript, python, c, variables

It seems to me that C programs should tend to have longer variable names, since the names will be destroyed by the compiler and won't make any difference to the performance or binary size of an optimized executable. I don't understand why in fact the opposite happens, in newer, interpreted languages where the name of the variable/method can actually affect performance, variables and methods routinely have much longer names compared to those in C. Is it just a product of the times, or is there a real reason behind this?

Comment: I am fairly sure for JS, the length of the variable names matters because you're sending every byte through the pipeline of the ol' interwebz. When  JS files are minified, they remove variable names and replace them with a single letter to reduce the request size.

Comment: If you're choosing to use a language that you know is likely to be significantly slower at runtime, but has more high-level features... then likely you value readability and ease of use over runtime speed...

Comment: *"I don't understand why in fact the opposite happens..."* -- citation needed.

Comment: Because newer is supposed to be better. And better supposed to allow more stuff.

Comment: Many modern languages, like Python, Ruby, and even Perl, semi-compile into some form of byte-code, so the variable names are only visible either in debugging or when an error occurs.  The executable file size is no indication of the performance (even for C).  Dynamic languages usually first compile at run-time, which is very fast.  The compilation time is usually insignificant compared to run-time, but that of course varies.  There are other optimisations involved, which differ between languages.

Comment: First, premature optimization is not a good idea.  I.e. without knowing how your names affect your memory use, pointless coding for it.  Second, that coding should generally be optimized towards reading, since you will often read code again and again, especially tricky code.  Last, where it would really matter, like embedded low RAM systems, Python is not the best of choice anyway.

Comment: @user3386109 as an example some code from django https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/sql.py#L7 and some from nginx https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/c3aed0a23392a509f64b740064f5f6633e8c89d8/src/http/modules/ngx_http_geo_module.c#L645. Are you honestly telling me that you think the latter is more verbose?

Comment: @cdarke  Python may optimize but I strongly suspect the strings to lookup variables in globals, locals and \__dict\__ namespaces are not altered.  So the OP may very well have a point.

Comment: @JLPeyret: yes, it affects key lengths.  However (for example)  the difference between a local vs. a global lookup can be significant and measurable.  Personally I'm never benchmarked for name lengths, I wonder if anyone here has (including the OP)?

Comment: @NateMara I'm saying that you made some pretty broad assertions, and provided no proof (in the question) to back them up. One example proves nothing. Where's your survey of trends in the industry, pulling from samples of 1000's of projects.

Comment: @user3386109 Okay, so perhaps I should have said "It seems to me that the opposite happens," here you go http://www.growthengineering.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Pedantic-Superstar.png

Comment: C doesn't have anything like modules, `from` imports, or `using` declarations. If you had to type `ngx_http_geo` in front of everything to avoid name collisions, you wouldn't be terribly inclined to make the rest of the name verbose either. Also, a lot of C was designed back when long names would have been an unacceptable burden on the computer *even at compilation time*, and when people were using teleprinters and line editors.

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty subjective question--it probably depends on who you ask. But if you ask me, the reason is that C is not Object-Oriented, and is an old language that has a lot of developers following old rules. There's no good reason *not* to use descriptive variable names in C--you're right, the compiler discards things like variable names anyway.

But the teachings of descriptive naming are still relatively new (relative to, say, the existence of C). So I think the reason that descriptive naming is more prevalent in modern languages is simply because the same group of people that tend to change and adapt to these new methodologies, also are more open to using newer languages.

But again, OOP is a very core reason as well. The [Java Coding Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) of old put a lot of focus on naming things clearly, and that has permeated the culture of Object Oriented Programming. You'll find that C++ projects often use longer, better names than C projects.

Short code should never be your goal. Even in languages like JavaScript, where the amount of bytes transferred can affect performance, use names that are descriptive (but not *too verbose*), and minify it later using the many available minification tools.

Comment: *the teachings of descriptive naming are still relatively new*  Sorry, I can't let that pass.  This was all the rage in the early 1970s to my personal knowledge, even before C.

Comment: *Old dogs can't learn new tricks* is a pretty unlikely reason. They probably know exactly what they're doing, and just value job security.

Comment: Hmm, didn't Python come out in 91?  And Java in 95?  Please, Java-fans, you did *not* invent OOP, much as Java books believe they have to teach all of us introductory OOP.  Try Smalltalk as inspiration instead.  ;-)

Comment: @JLPeyret I'm not a Java fan, but I feel it's object model is definitely superior to Python's, aside from multiple inheritance (if you're into that). I still see a lot of Python shell code with terrible variable names, but I generally see better in OO Python code. I never suggested it invented OOP, but I'd give it some credit for making it popular.

Comment: @cdarke As I said, it's very subjective and I'm sure everyone has their own answer. Add yours! :) Maybe I didn't say that well, but C culture certainly doesn't seem to teach using names like `isVerboseMode` or `hasEnabledAttribute`. In many very popular Open Source C projects would call it `verbose` and `enabled_attr`.

Comment: @Will Curious... is it mostly information hiding (*private*, *protected*, etc...) that you prefer in Java?  Agree, if that's your thing, you can't get it from Python.

Comment: @JLPeyret Python's easily my favorite language, but there are OO features that other languages support that Python does not. Visibility is one aspect, yes. Multiple constructors based on parameter types is another. Interfaces is another. The ability to make a *constructor* `private` or `protected`, specifically, is another. Abstract classes is another. Final methods is another. But I still love Python ;)

Comment: @4castle Good point :) And it's not that they *can't learn* new tricks, it's just an old trick that seems to be working fine that they see no reason to violate convention to change.

Answer (score 0):

Computers have gotten so staggeringly powerful that shorter or longer variable names make very little to no difference. But poorly named variables and functions, in *any* language, can cost a whole lot more money and waste way more time than any perceived performance hit you might take from using a longer name. The extra nanosecond of processing costs nobody anything, but the 45 minutes it takes a senior developer to figure out what the code is even doing costs *everybody* something.

Comment: wonder why this is downvoted.  seems rather obvious to me.